# check array of objects if have same key and sum value

Tags: javascript

I have a array that contains these objects. What I want is sum values with same key. For example,

```
let data = [
  {
    name: "fieldA",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "building",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "fieldA",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "building",
    value: 20,
  },
];
```

And the result should be:

```
[
  {
    name: "fieldA",
    value: 40,
  },
  {
    name: "building",
    value: 40,
  }
];
```

How to do it? Is it possible to do it with `map` function?

Comment: No, it's not possible to use the `map` function to achieve the result you want. You are able to use `reduce` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: 'fieldA',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'building',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'fieldA',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'building',
        value: 20,
    },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const findName = acc.find(_ => _.name === val.name);

    if (findName) {
        findName.value += val.value;
    } else {
        acc.push(val);
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `reduce()` to achieve that:

```js
var data = [ { name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, { name: "building", value: 20, }, { name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, { name: "building", value: 20, }];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{name, value})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {name, value:0};
    acc[name].value+=value;
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you objects seem to have the same 'value', assuming that's intentional, here's my solution...not super elegant but does the job

```js
let data = [{
    name: "fieldA",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "building",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "fieldA",
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "building",
    value: 20,
  },
];

function matchValue(param, val) {
  let matches = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    console.log(param[i]);
    if (param[i].value === val) {
      matches.push(param[i]);
    }
  }
  return matches;
}

console.log(matchValue(data, 20));
```