# how to sum value of same keys and add a key with value that contains array of id same keys, in array of objects for each object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains these objects. What I want is sum values with same key and add a key contains id same keys that were match toghther. For example,

```
var data = [ 
     {id:1, name: "fieldA", value: 20, },
     {id:2, name: "building", value: 20, },
     {id:3, name: "fieldA", value: 20, },
     {id:4, name: "building", value: 20, }
    ];
```

have to become something like it:

```
var data = [
 {id:1,idd:[1,3], name: "fieldA", value: 40, },
 {id:2,idd:[2,4], name: "building", value: 40, },
];
```

i have used this code: but i cant reach what i told above! :

```
var data = [ {id:1,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, {id:2,id2:[], name: "building", value: 20, }, {id:3,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, {id:4,id2:[], name: "building", value: 20, }];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{id,id2, name, value})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {id,id2, name, value:0};
    acc[name].value +=value;
    acc[name].id2[id2.length]= acc[name].id
/*     console.log(acc[name])
     */        return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

i decide use reduce and map as it can. thanks.

note: this code has inspired from this question:

> [check array of objects if have same key and sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322978/check-array-of-objects-if-have-same-key-and-sum-value)

Comment: Should it be `value: 40` in the output objects?

Comment: yes indeed it have to be 40! but i wrongly wrote 20!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is push the correct `id`, which you have already extracted using destructuring.

Also since you do not want to add the individual `value`s, you can just omit the `+` sign to have the last `value`.

```js
var data = [ {id:1,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, {id:2,id2:[], name: "building", value: 20, }, {id:3,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 20, }, {id:4,id2:[], name: "building", value: 20, }];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{id,id2, name, value})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {id,id2, name, value:0};
    acc[name].value += value;
    acc[name].id2.push(id);
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks you for correcting my code you and @Nitheesh has correct answer

Comment: Yes. Stuff like this is ideally done with `reduce()` (look it up). But I wanted to point out improvements in your code, so you can understand better.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array.reduce` in javascript.

Just parse the accumulator array to find the node with combination of name and value. If that combination is not found, push the current node with id of current node in `idd` key. Or else push the id of current node to the `idd` key of node from the accumulator array.

```js
var data = [ 
  {id:1, name: "fieldA", value: 20, },
  {id:2, name: "building", value: 20, },
  {id:3, name: "fieldA", value: 20, },
  {id:4, name: "building", value: 20, }
];

const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find((item) => item.name === curr.name && item.value === curr.value);
  if (node) {
    node.idd.push(curr.id);
    node.value += curr.value;
  } else {
    acc.push({ ...curr, idd: [curr.id]})
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: thanks alot, i give above question as an answer as he corect my code while u answer the question without having idd in main object and its really great :)

Comment: var data = [ {id:1, name: "fieldA", value: 10, }, {id:2, name: "building", value: 20, }, {id:3, name: "fieldA", value: 30, }, {id:4, name: "building", value: 40, }, ]; const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => { const node = acc.find((item) => item.name === curr.name ); if (node) { node.value += curr.value; node.idd.push(curr.id) } else { acc.push({ ...curr, idd: [curr.id]}) } return acc; }, []); console.log(output) // i just have done some eddition

Comment: Oops. that was amistake from my end. I didnt updated the value for same node. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you just need to replace your line

```
acc[name].id2[id2.length]= acc[name].id
```

with

```
acc[name].id2.push(id)
```

So this:

```
var data = [ 
    {id:1,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 1, }, 
    {id:2,id2:[], name: "building", value: 5, }, 
    {id:3,id2:[], name: "fieldA", value: 21, }, 
    {id:4,id2:[], name: "building", value: 85, }
];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{id,id2, name, value})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {id,id2, name, value:0};
    acc[name].value +=value;
    acc[name].id2.push(id)
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

will output:

```
[
    { id: 1, id2: [ 1, 3 ], name: 'fieldA', value: 22 },
    { id: 2, id2: [ 2, 4 ], name: 'building', value: 90 }
]
```